# Use number of iteration in for-loop instead of element of list

Tags: python, for-loop

I am not sure if this has been asked before, and I apologize if it has been, but I have the following simple lines of code:

```
for s in lst_times:
        #print(s)
        f.write( str() + " " + str(s)+ " " + "\n" )
```

Is there any way for me to, in this loop, use the actual integer value of s instead of the element with index s in the list lst_times ?

Thank you for your time,

Comment: @zenith I apologize, I'll add it..

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but: `f.write( str() + " " + str(s) + " " + "\n" )` is equal to `f.write(" " + str(s) + " \n")`

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen I'm aware of that, I just stripped it for the sake of simplicity. Thanks for mentioning this though (:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function

```
for i, s in enumerate(lst_times):
    #print(s)
    f.write( str() + " " + str(s)+ " " + "\n" )
```

Answer (score 3):

Two ways:

```
for i in range(len(lst_times)):
    f.write(...

for i, s in enumerate(lst_times):
    f.write(...
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `range`, you can use `xrange` to lazily evaluate index. `xrange` will return an iterator object and will keep only one number in a memory at a time (opposed to `range`, which will keep a list of numbers).

```
for i in xrange(len(lst_times)):
    f.write(...)
    # lst_times[i] will give you `ith` element.
```

p.s. - `xrange` is only in python 2.x. python 3's `range` works like python 2.x's `xrange`